# Entity Framework, how to treat a view as a child table

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer

I have a table, call it Transaction, and a view, call it TransactionExtra, which is based on Transaction, e.g., `create view TransactionExtra select t.id as t_id, x.* from Transaction t join X x on ....`

In Entity Framework, I'd like to be able to access TransactionExtras objects from Transaction objects, ("create a navigation property") e.g., transaction.TransactionExtra, just as if TransactionExtra  were a table with a foreign key to T.

How can I do this in the EDMX visual editor?

At present I'm doing it manually:

```
static TransactionExtra extra(Entities db, transaction t)
{
    return db.TransactionExtra.Where(x => x.t_id == t.id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

For every Transaction there is zero or one TransactionExtra.

I can't seem to figure out how to tell EntityFrameworkEDMX to map the property.

Thanks.